# grep pattern with leading spaces

Tags: bash, grep, regex

I need some help in setting the correct pattern for grep. I need to find all occurrences of `pattern` where line *may have*  leading space(s). For example: In the following file:

```
 1. No pattern recognized.
 2. Pattern to be recognized
 3.          Pattern to be recognized here also
 4.  pattern with only one leading space
```

I would like to grep only lines 2,3 and 4. The line numbers are just for the reference.

So far I have tried the following:

`grep -i '^ [[:blank:]]pattern'`, but it returns only line 4.

`grep -i '[[:blank:]]pattern'` returns 1,3 and 4.

`grep -i '^[[:blank:]]pattern'` returns 1,3 and 4.

-- Mike
P.S.
If this is not the appropriate forum, then please guide me accordingly.

Comment: What is the difference  between 3 and 4? they both start with space right?

Comment: Can't you simply match zero or more spaces at the start i.e. `grep '^ *Pattern' file`? (or `'^[ \t]*Pattern'` for spaces or tabs; or `'^[[:blank:]]*Pattern'` for any horizontal whitespace)

Comment: @Ravexina, the diff is number of spaces. As in my first attempt, I was getting only 4 and not 3.

Comment: Thanks, @steeldriver,  I was missing `*` between the `blank` and the `pattern`. Its working!

Answer (score 7):

Your line 2 and 3 has upper case P and requires zero or more spaces, so specify exactly that:

```
$ grep '[[:blank:]]*Pattern'  input.txt                                  
 Pattern to be recognized
         Pattern to be recognized here also
```

Personally, I'd recommend extending your pattern with something else, like `'[[:blank:]]Pattern.*recognized'`

Comment: Thanks. Its working.
To take care of uppercase and lowercase, I use `grep -i`.  I was actually missing `*` between the `[[:blank:]]` and the `pattern` in my first attempt. But what I actually wanted was `grep '^[[:blank:]]*Pattern'  input.txt`, otherwise it returns 1 as well.

Comment: @MikeV.D.C. well, assuming your input is the same as your example, you have leading spaces in each line. So with `grep -i` it doesn't quite work.  I guess it would be much better if we knew the actual data and pattern you're trying to do

Comment: The numbers in the sample are just for reference. May be I should have mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: Ah,so lines 1 and 4 actually don't have leading space ?

Comment: Line 1 doesnt have, but line 4 *has* one.

Answer (score 2):

What I get is you want either no leading space at all, like line #2 or more than of one space, cause you are excluding line #4 which has one space.

so I suggest:

```
egrep -i '^\s*pattern' file.txt | grep -v '^\spattern'
```

or using a single `awk`:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /^\s*pattern/ && !/^\spattern/ ' file.txt
```

- `\s` as space you can change it with `blank` if you want.
- `egrep -i '^\s*pattern' file.txt` first we get all lines started with or without any times leading space following by pattern.
- `grep -v '^\spattern'`: then we exclude the ones which contains exactly one leading space.

The above example works on a file without numbering, if your file contains leading numbers use this one:

```
egrep -i '\s*pattern' file.txt | grep -v '\spattern'
```

or for `awk`:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /\s*pattern/ && !/\spattern/ ' file.txt
```